# trigger on 2 tables one to many

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Here are two tables :
table1

```
id1(pk) objectid z
0        1       100
1        2       98
```

table2

```
id2(pk) n_sd prof alt_inf
0        1   5
1        1   15
2        2   8
```

objectid -> n_sd (1->n).

The aim of the trigger is on insert on table2 to do the maths alt_inf = z-prof for objectid = n_sd.

```
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
NEW.alti_inf = (select z-NEW.prof from table1 join table2
on table2.n_sd = table1.objectid 
where new.gid = table2.gid )
RETURN NEW;
END IF ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_calcul_altiinf ON table2 ;
CREATE TRIGGER trg_calcul_altiinf AFTER INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calcul_altiInf();
```

I have no result nor error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a trigger fired AFTER the insertion it makes no sense to modify the NEW record, as it has been already inserted. Use a BEFORE trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_calcul_altiinf 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table2    -- + UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calcul_altiInf();
```

In the function body you should query only the `table1`, as the current value of `n_sd` is in the NEW record:

```
IF TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN    -- + UPDATE
    NEW.alti_inf = (
        SELECT z - NEW.prof 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE NEW.n_sd = table1.objectid);
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

Comment: more simple indeed. Thanks a lot for the explanation of BEFORE and AFTER that are not obvious to me.

Comment: In case of UPDATE, I Wrote
`NEW.alti_inf = (select z - NEW.prof from test.table1 where OLD.n_sd = objectid);`
It does not work. And the first thing I wonder about is : should I use `UPDATE table1  SET NEW.alti=...` ?
I tried but as it failed as well, I don't kow which part is wrong (maybe both !). Thx

Comment: In case of UPDATE the logic is exactly the same, see the edited answer.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about but update fails. I tried also : `IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
 NEW.alti_inf = (select z - NEW.prof from table1 where NEW.n_sd = objectid) ;
        RETURN NEW ;
 -- A la mise à jour, calcul de l'altitude inférieure
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        --UPDATE .unite_strati SET
        NEW.alti_inf = (select z - NEW.prof from table1 where OLD.n_sd = objectid);
        RETURN NEW ;
        END IF ;`
No way...

Comment: It works pretty well, [test it here.](http://rextester.com/NRIDN38015)

Comment: Jeeeeezz, update was working for this morning !! I couldn't see it just because I was not refreshing the screen each time...Anw thx for your attention.